# Convert Datatable to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I get a code for converting datatable to pdf in Asp.net Web application. I want  to have functionality to export `datatable` into  `PDF`. I found [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-DataSet-or-DataTable-to-Word-Excel-PDF-and-CSV-Formats.aspx) article but it is using `gridview` for exporting

Comment: so what is problem with gridview. you don't need to show gridview in you page. it's just take for creating HTML tabular format for your pdf data..

Comment: I am not showing grid view on page

Comment: I am also saying that your data will not display in gridview. it;s just take from generate html view for generate pdf. Either you can go with iTextSharp but you need to put many effort for doing this.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without gridview?

Comment: yeah you can do it as below posted answer with use of iTextSharp  library. Actually above suggested url also using iTextSharp library but it wrapper with some method so you can directly generate PDF by html.

Comment: Use any third part libarary [As mentioned other about ItextSharp e.t.c]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using iTextSharp,you can do it.It can be download from internet and it is free.
Please, find the code below,

```
   public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt,string strFilePath)
   {      
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
    PdfPRow row = null;
    float[] widths = new float[dt.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        widths[i] = 4f;

    table.SetWidths(widths);

    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
    int iCol = 0;
    string colname = "";
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));

    cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
    }

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < dt.Columns.Count; h++)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[h].ToString(), font5));
            }
        }          
    }
    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: datatable is throwing an error .is there any conflict with  type datatable

Answer (score 5):

You can't "**convert**" a `DataTable` to a PDF Document. But you can **insert** data into it as normal content.

This would have to be done through a data control, like the `GridView` or `ListView`; just like in a normal webpage. Which is why the [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-DataSet-or-DataTable-to-Word-Excel-PDF-and-CSV-Formats.aspx) you have linked to does that. `GridView` is probably the closest and easiest way to make it aesthetically appear the same as a `DataTable`. As it will just be stored as a normal table in the PDF Document.

Note that the `GridView` is created in memory - you don't create or need to have one in your HTML page. Try and experiment with the code to understand this better.

So I recommend following the [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-DataSet-or-DataTable-to-Word-Excel-PDF-and-CSV-Formats.aspx).