# how to create PDF files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am first time facing to create pdf files. I came across iTextSharp, but not able to find how to convert Listview to pdf tables. Creating custom tables, take lots of time, can any one tell me how can I export my listview ( I have set of 5-6 Listview with complex structure) to PDF, additionally, I want to put images also.

Can this be done with Crystal Report, I am using Visual web developer 2008 express edition.

Thanks.

Comment: First,try to convert Listview to datatable and then,you can use iTextsharp to create PDF files.

Comment: @MahaSwetha: Thanks for your reply. Can you give some link for example.

Comment: you can refer for iTextsharp -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927675/convert-datatable-to-pdf/13927803#13927803