# How to genenerate a pdf file with tabular data

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I have a collection of objects, which have fields e.g. Name, Age, Size. 
How can I generate a pdf stream (to be used as an email attachment afterwards) that would have this data in form of a table with records corresponding to the objects in the collection?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate pdf file after retrieving the information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244348/generate-pdf-file-after-retrieving-the-information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use iTextSharp for that I for example if you have a Data Table and you want to convert it to PDF using itextsharp see this link :
[using I text sharp to convert Data Table to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927675/convert-datatable-to-pdf)